# Tkinter widgets not appearing

Tags: python-2.7, widget, tkinter

I was testing an app I was writing but I just get a blank window and no widgets.

```
from Tkinter import*
class App(Frame):

def _init_(self, master):

    frame = Frame(master)
    frane.pack()

    self.instruction = Label(frame, text = 'Password:')
    self.instruction.pack()

    self.button = Button(frame, text = 'Enter', command = self.reveal)
    self.button.pack()


root = Tk()
root.title('Password')
root.geometry('350x250')
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of typos. The first is in the name of the constructor method:

```
def _init_(self, master):
```

Should read:

```
def __init__(self, master):
```

Note the double underscore - see [the docs for Python objects](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=class%20__init__#object.__init__).

The second is inside your constructor:

```
frane.pack()
```

You're also missing a declaration for a method named 'reveal' in your App class:

```
self.button = Button(frame, text="Enter", command=self.reveal)
```

The working example reads:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        frame = Frame()
        frame.pack()

        self.instruction = Label(frame, text="Password:")
        self.instruction.pack()

        self.button = Button(frame, text="Enter", command=self.reveal)
        self.button.pack()


    def reveal(self):
        # Do something.
        pass


root = Tk()
root.title("Password")
root.geometry("350x250")
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

See also: [The Tkinter documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program).